# Is there a way to have p5js run the same script multiple times but to read different input parameters each time? Is it possible to convert to an exe?

Tags: javascript, graphics, 3d, p5.js

I was wondering if it is possible to convert a complex p5js project to an executable that would allow me to run it many thousands of times but with different input parameters?  Alternatively, is it possible to loop and reset the same script many times and only update the input parameters?

A very simple example is given below

```
function setup() {
 
  i = 1;
  c = createCanvas(400, 400);

  colorMode(HSB, 1);

  C_array = [];
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) C_array[i] = 1 / i;

}

function draw() {
  background(C_array[i], 1, 1);

  saveCanvas();
  i++;
  c.reset;
}
```

**UPDATED**

I am attempting a different way now and trying to have the page reload after each sketch finishes just after saving the image.  The problem is it either saves a load of exactly the same image or it reloads too quickly before the image can be saved.

```
function setup() {
   
  i = 0;
  c = createCanvas(400, 400);

  colorMode(HSB, 1);

a=random();
}

function draw() {
  background(a, 1, 1);

  i++;
    
  if(i>120){
  saveCanvas();
    location.reload
  }
}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure if these two things are possible but I'm pretty sure you don't have to do that anyway. You can simply write a p5 program that does that. Instead of running your script over and over, just write a function that does what you want and call it over and over, inside your program.

Comment: @ChrisG  thank you for your response. Do you mean it is possible to call a p5js script from within another javascript script while changing the input parameters for the p5js script?

Comment: Can you give an example of what these input parameters are? And how you're accessing them inside your script?